# SuiteScript - Determing when TimeSheet is Submitted

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Ultimate goal: I want to have validation when a Timesheet is submitted.

Issue: Unable to determine when timesheet is submitted

In Before Record Submit in 2.0, when I log scriptContext.type for submitting a timesheet, it is always edit (fun fact: Retract is its own event, but I guess submit is not. Retract is not listed in the UserEventType enum)

I then looked at the approval status - in the UI, this changes when you hit submit. So I thought to grab the old vs new and if that changed (and the new value is pending approval), then it was submitted. This proved perplexing:
On submit, the old and new value is 2 (Pending Approval)
On retract (only did to keep re-testing), the old and new value is 1 (Open).
In either case, they are the same value so I can't compare old vs new

Below is my code. **How can I determine that the timesheet has been submitted?**

```
function beforeSubmit(scriptContext) {
            var contextType = scriptContext.type;
            log.debug('afterSubmit contextType', contextType);//figure out what submit is
            //submit is not its own event type, just edit and changes approval status
            var oldRecord = scriptContext.oldRecord;
            var newRecord = scriptContext.newRecord;
            var oldApprovalStatus = oldRecord.getValue('approvalstatus');
            var newApprovalStatus = newRecord.getValue('approvalstatus');

            log.debug('oldApprovalStatus', oldApprovalStatus);
            log.debug('newApprovalStatus', newApprovalStatus);
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps something else is modifying your timesheet's approval satus but your UE is not firing on that external change because your deployment is in Testing mode (i.e. for your user only).

Answer (score 0):

The `APPROVE` event is fired during the `afterSubmit` entry point, not `beforeSubmit`.

When a Timesheet is approved, `afterSubmit` will fire with a `scriptContext.type` of `scriptContext.UserEventType.APPROVE`.

```js
define([], () => {
  function afterSubmit(scriptContext) {
    if (scriptContext.type !== scriptContext.UserEventType.APPROVE) {
      // Exit on any event besides APPROVE
      return;
    }

    // Timesheet has been approved
    // do stuff here ...
  }

  return {
    afterSubmit
  };
})
```